# Android studio Activity disappeared when trying to fix layout issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i was following my Android studio course in college and was struggling with the main activity always giving me errors, i saw there was a Fix button and pressed it, but the whole Activity disappeared and havent found a way to fix it or at least get back to where i started. [image: No activity shown][image: The errors i got after pressing the "fix" button]

Comment: you are currently on the design tab, and when there is an error, the layout is not displayed there, if you go to code tab, you still have the code. but can you show other errors?

Comment: Same as @Yura , I would suggest you to click on the "Code" tab and take a screenshot showing your layout XML